# useState not showing intermediate steps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a sorting visualiser and I've already completed it for bubble, insertion and selection. I am facing a problem with merge sort because it involves recursion and there seems to be some issue in updating the state variable.

```js
async function mergeSort(arr, setArr, mainArray) {
  let n = arr.length;
  if (n === 1) {
    return arr;
  }

  let leftArray = arr.slice(0, Math.floor(n / 2));
  let rightArray = arr.slice(Math.floor(n / 2), n);

  leftArray = await mergeSort(leftArray, setArr, mainArray);
  rightArray = await mergeSort(rightArray, setArr, mainArray);

  let mergeResultArray = await merge(leftArray, rightArray);
  let l = mergeResultArray.length;
  let tempArr = [...mergeResultArray];
  let copyArr = [...mainArray];
  let subArr = copyArr.slice(l, mainArray.length);
  tempArr.push(...subArr);
  setArr(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tempArr)));

  return mergeResultArray;
}
```

```js
async function merge(array1, array2) {
  let array3 = [];

  while (array1.length && array2.length) {
    await delay(DELAY);
    if (array1[0].val > array2[0].val) {
      array3.push(array2[0]);
      array2.splice(0, 1);
    } else {
      array3.push(array1[0]);
      array1.splice(0, 1);
    }
  }

  while (array1.length) {
    await delay(DELAY);
    array3.push(array1[0]);
    array1.splice(0, 1);
  }

  while (array2.length) {
    await delay(DELAY);
    array3.push(array2[0]);
    array2.splice(0, 1);
  }

  return array3;
}
```

```js
const delay = (DELAY) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("");
    }, DELAY);
  });
};
```

`setArr` is the function returned by `useState` to update the array on the main component which is being passed to the function. The part after `await merge()` is just to create the current `mainArray` after merging the parts after each step to visualise the intermediate steps.

Right now what's happening is that after the function is called, the main component goes blank where the array is supposed to be and after some time, it appears and it is completely sorted. The intermediate `setArr()` are not showing on the component.

After learning that `setArr(arr)` takes significant time (laziness) (because it was delayed in other sorting algorithms as well), I used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` to render it immediately.

What could be the issue and how do I fix this to show all intermediate steps ?

Also, I'm getting this error

`index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. at Bar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:281:13) at li`

if it helps

Comment: There is no use of awaiting the mergeSort as it is not returning any promise. could you show merge method.

Comment: I've added the merge() and delay() which is used inside merge() to create a synchronous lag for the animation.

Comment: Also I'll remove the await from mergeSort(). For some reason it was not working previously and it did after I added await and I was confused too as to why it was working. I've made many edits after that, I'll check if there's a problem with that still

Comment: please provide a minimum viable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ideally a codesandbox link or a reproduction within stackoverflow script repl

Comment: Please clone this https://github.com/SPARTACUS5329/sorting-visualiser/tree/minimal (minimal branch). If there is a better method to do this for react please let me know.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about the solution or even the exact problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited on Nov 12.

I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/visual-merge-sort-10juw). A lot of changes, even typescript added (I don't like programming without the support of types.). Hopefully, it's helpful.

---

In my understanding, the best approach to make complicated calculations in React Components(also hooks) is `never do that in React Components`. There are strict rules to write codes in React, such as ticker of re-rendering,  rules of hooks, etc. Mixing complicated calculations with React leads to unexpected behaviors and is hard to debug. Instead, move it out of React, subscribe to the results after the component is mounted, and unsubscribe before unmounting. That's all my understanding about avoiding errors in React that letting React only do the views.

Comment: I've understood the idea of your solution. Can you show how to code it? The repo link is in the comments if you need it as a base.

Comment: @SPARTACUS5329 I created a sandbox based on your repo, lots of new code. Hopefully, it's still helpful.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I think I'll be able to figure it out from here. I don't use TS because I haven't learnt it yet, but I can understand it so I'll be able understand the logic and transpose it to JS.

Comment: @SPARTACUS5329 Good for you

Answer (score 2):

## Why `useState` seems to skip steps

TBD. (I'll update this answer when I know for sure)

## The error from `useState`

That error fires if a `setState` is called after a component has unmounted. In your code on Github, you trigger the sorting, which is an async process, but you don't have anything in place to cancel that process if you unmount the component midway through the process. This is why that error happens. The component is no longer rendered and you're still trying to update its state.

## Using Generator Functions instead

A much better way to do what you're doing would be to use Generator functions instead of Async function. Generator functions are almost exactly the same as async function, except, you use the work `yield` instead of await. That way, the function goes and "pauses" on every yield and you're able to resume it manually externally.

This will make you're visualizer better too as you won't need a static `DELAY` and you'll be able to let the user click through one step at a time.

Best of all, your code will look mostly the same. And if you still want to automatically advance through the visualization, you'll be able to put a `setInterval` in the React component itself which will be easier to clean up on unmount.

Here's a basic example of how Generator functions would work:

```
function* mergeSort(arr, setArr, mainArray) {
  let n = arr.length;
  if (n === 1) {
    return arr;
  }

  let leftArray = arr.slice(0, Math.floor(n / 2));
  let rightArray = arr.slice(Math.floor(n / 2), n);

  leftArray = yield* mergeSort(leftArray, setArr, mainArray);
  rightArray = yield* mergeSort(rightArray, setArr, mainArray);

  let mergeResultArray = yield* merge(leftArray, rightArray);
  let l = mergeResultArray.length;
  let tempArr = [...mergeResultArray];
  let copyArr = [...mainArray];
  let subArr = copyArr.slice(l, mainArray.length);
  tempArr.push(...subArr);
  // Cheaper way to copy.
  setArr(tempArr.slice());

  return mergeResultArray;
}
function* merge(array1, array2) {
  let array3 = [];

  while (array1.length && array2.length) {
    yield;
    if (array1[0].val > array2[0].val) {
      array3.push(array2[0]);
      array2.splice(0, 1);
    } else {
      array3.push(array1[0]);
      array1.splice(0, 1);
    }
  }

  while (array1.length) {
    yield;
    array3.push(array1[0]);
    array1.splice(0, 1);
  }

  while (array2.length) {
    yield;
    array3.push(array2[0]);
    array2.splice(0, 1);
  }
  return array3;
}

// Usage within React:

  let [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  let iterRef = useRef();

  const generateNewArray = () => {
    setArray(generateRandomArr(5, 650, ARRAY_SIZE));
  };

  const mergeSortStep = () => {
    // This will do one step on every click.
    iterRef.current.next();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setArray(generateRandomArr(5, 650, ARRAY_SIZE));
    iterRef.current = mergeSort([...array], setArray, [...array]);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I'm familiar with the concept of yield, but this isn't working. When I click the button, I'm getting the error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I added `event.preventDefault()` to `onClick` but I'm still getting the same error. Is this working for you? If it is do you mind creating a pr to the repo?

Comment: I've just found the cause of the error. It is because inside `mergeSort`, `mergeSort()` is being `yield*`ed. There is no `yield` before that so there is a maximum call stack. And `mergeResultArray` cannot be `yielded` before calling `mergeSort`

Answer (score 2):

@naman-goel has already provided you with a great answer but I wanted to add that you don't have to necessarily do the visualization while doing the sorting, you can also do the sort and store the steps, then later on do the visualization separately.  That way you can also store the state for the visualization without doing the sort again.  If you really wanted to go the extra mile you can also then use canvas to draw the visualization instead of rerendering a component on every step so it doesn't look like constant flickering.

React will also batch update every 10ms or something, so if your state update is happening 10 times in that 10ms period it also won't show all your visualization, it will just jump to the next ~10 steps.